# How to use lassoglm in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have this issue while using the lassoglm function in matlab. My matlab says that the statistics toolbox is installed. However, I couldn't see lassoglm function available in my matlab

Answer (score 0):

Your Matlab version isn't recent enough.

It isn't there on my R2010a version. The documentation on the website is for 2012b.